# I have a quick question about how this linked list merging code works

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

Im confused on how head.next returns the entire list instead of a next value such l1,l2,dummy .next does in the code below. particularly I'm wondering how head.next returns an entire sorted array and skips the -1 value that was input on the second line.

```
let mergeTwoLists = function (l1, l2) {
  let dummy = new ListNode(-1);
  let head = dummy;

  while (l1 !== null && l2 !== null) {
    if (l1.val <= l2.val) {
      dummy.next = l1;
      l1 = l1.next;
    } else {
      dummy.next = l2;
      l2 = l2.next;
    }
    dummy = dummy.next;
  }

  if (l1 !== null) {
    dummy.next = l1;
  } else {
    dummy.next = l2;
  }

  return head.next;
};

class ListNode {
  constructor(val = null, next = null) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Returning `head.next` obviously skips the first node. It doesn't return a sorted list. It returns a specially merged list that happens to be sorted if both the input lists are already sorted.

Comment: so it skips the first node and returns the rest of the nodes?

Comment: It returns *a* node that happens to have a `next` key that might link another node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps when visualising how the list is built:

Let the input be a list with values [3, 9] and another with just [4]:

```
 l1
 ↓
 3 → 9 → null

 l2
 ↓
 4 → null
```

Before the loop starts a new node is created:

```
head
 ↓
-1
 ↑
dummy
```

The loop will make its first iteration, and the `if` condition is true. First `dummmy.next` is adapted, which leads to this situation:

```
head l1
 ↓   ↓
-1 → 3 → 9 → null
 ↑
dummy    

 l2
 ↓
 4 → null
```

... and then `l1` is reassigned a new reference:

```
head     l1
 ↓       ↓
-1 → 3 → 9 → null
 ↑
dummy    

 l2
 ↓
 4 → null
```

The last statement in the loop assigns a new reference to `dummy`:

```
head     l1
 ↓       ↓
-1 → 3 → 9 → null
     ↑
    dummy    

 l2
 ↓
 4 → null
```

The loop iterates a second time, and the `if` condition is now false, so we get in the `else` block. First `dummmy.next` is adapted (this breaks the link it had with `l1`, and so I move the visualisation of `l1` and `l2`):

```
head     l2
 ↓       ↓
-1 → 3 → 4 → null
     ↑
    dummy    

 l1
 ↓
 9 → null
```

... and then `l1` is reassigned a new reference, in this case it becomes `null`:

```
head          l2
 ↓            ↓
-1 → 3 → 4 → null
     ↑
    dummy    

 l1
 ↓
 9 → null
```

The last statement in the loop assigns a new reference to `dummy`:

```
head          l2
 ↓            ↓
-1 → 3 → 4 → null
         ↑
        dummy    

 l1
 ↓
 9 → null
```

At this stage the loop condition is no longer true (`l2` is `null`), and so the `if` block that follows the loop is executed. This links `dummy.next` with the remaining (not `null`) reference. Again, for sake of the visualisation, I swap the position of `l1` and `l2`:

```
head         l1
 ↓           ↓
-1 → 3 → 4 → 9 → null
         ↑
        dummy    

 l2
 ↓
null
```

Now we get to the final statement: `return head.next`. Notice how `head` did not *ever* move away from the new node that was created at the start.

So the returned reference is:

```
head         l1
 ↓           ↓
-1 → 3 → 4 → 9 → null
     ↑
    returned    

 l2
 ↓
null
```

Note how `head` keeps pointing to the node with -1 during the whole execution of this function. The temporary node with value -1 will be garbage collected, as there is no variable referencing it any more once the function has returned (`head` is a *local* variable).

Comment: I truly appreciate your time